# Как сделать, чтобы иконка в Google Maps меняла своё расположение?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Мне нужно, что бы со временем добавлялись иконки (или же чтобы одна существующая изменяла свои координаты).

Итак, как же сделать, что бы иконка в Google Maps меняла своё расположение со временем?

Код:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 30, lng: 40},
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: 8
        });

  var image = 'Strelka.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 30, lng:40},
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: 'Strelka'
      });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Добавьте код, который в данный момент добавляет карту.

Comment: Добавил код который добавляет карту

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать объект с новыми координатами и обновить их в маркере.

```
var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
beachMarker.setPosition(newLatLng);
```

Это можно делать с определенным интервалом с помощью функции `setInterval`.

Comment: У меня не работает(( Можете отправить полный вариант кода?
С задержкой допустим 5с

Comment: Все окей работает
Можете объяснить что делает эта строчка "var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);" ?

Comment: По сути это просто объект, который хранит широту и долготу, а строка создает этот объект и присваивает его в переменную. Более подробно можно прочитать тут https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng